# Selecting ansible_user in compose based on a ec2 inventory tag

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I'm trying to get a list of ec2 hosts that are divided into two groups of tags `tag_OS_ec2_user` and `tag_OS_ubuntu`, but there is a problem with determining the value of ansible_user depending on the tag that includes the host for connecting to dynamic inventory hosts.

Here is the condition under which hosts are connected via login, depending on whether the host is included in the tag or not:

ec2-inventory.yml:

```yaml
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - eu-north-1

filters:

keyed_groups:
  - prefix: region_is
    key: placement.region
    
  - prefix: arch
    key: architecture

  - prefix: tag
    key: tags
  
compose:
  ansible_user: "{{ 'ec2-user' if 'tag_OS_ec2_user' in tags else ('ubuntu' if 'tag_OS_ubuntu' in tags else '') }}"
```

Inventory output:

```json
"tag_OS_ec2_user": {
        "hosts": [
            "ec2-1-1-1-1.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
            "ec2-2-2-2-2.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
        ]
    },
    "tag_OS_ubuntu": {
        "hosts": [
            "ec2-3-3-3-3.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
            "ec2-3-3-3-3.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
        ]
```

But the problem is that even when passing ansible_user: `{{ 'ec2-user' }}` for only one tag `tag_OS_ec2_user` the ansible does not see the string in jinja format. When i pass just `'ec2-user'` ssh login is successful

I want connect to host via ssh with a tag-based

Comment: The values in `compose` are template for you already, so you could try `ansible_user: "'ec2-user' if 'tag_OS_ec2_user' in tags else ('ubuntu' if 'tag_OS_ubuntu' in tags else '')"`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Same issue. I login as the user from whom the ansible is running. Idk why

Comment: I tried this but now the ansible connects as the defaul-user. It seems he doesn't see the tags"'ec2-user' if 'tag_OS_ec2_user' in tags else ('ubuntu' if 'tag_OS_ubuntu' in tags else 'default-user')"

Comment: I would suspect that `tags` is not really what you think it is (possibly colliding with something else?). Could you show more context around your `Inventory output`? (aka the exact json structure leading to it)